# How to Capture packets generated from linux pktgen traffic generator?

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump

I am testing an openflow switch for its performance. I am using "pktgen" kernel module  available in linux to generate packets at different flow rates. I have a host with two interfaces eth1 and eth2. Both interfaces are connected to switch port1 and port2 respectively. I am injecting traffic from eth1 using pktgen. Simultaneously I am also running tcpdump on eth1 interface.

However I am not able to see the traffic that is being generated by the host on eth1 interface. I used `tcpdump -i eth1 -f udp port 9` to view traffic as packets generated by pktgen are on udp port 9.

I did look for possible solutions on Google and the closest thing to a solution is [this thread](https://www.spinics.net/lists/vlan/msg01051.html).

However I am still not able to see any traffic generated by pktgen on eth1 interface. Please let me know if there are any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance!!!

Please see below the pktgen script i am using.

```
function pgset() {
local result

echo $1 > $PGDEV

result=`cat $PGDEV | fgrep "Result: OK:"`
if [ "$result" = "" ]; then
     cat $PGDEV | grep Result:
fi
}

function pg() {
    echo inject > $PGDEV
    cat $PGDEV
}

PGDEV=/proc/net/pktgen/kpktgend_0
echo "Removing all devices"
pgset "rem_device_all"
echo "Adding eth1"
pgset "add_device eth1"

CLONE_SKB="clone_skb 10"
PKT_SIZE="pkt_size 60"

COUNT="count 100"     
DELAY="delay 0" 

PGDEV=/proc/net/pktgen/eth1
echo "Configuring $PGDEV"
pgset "$COUNT"
pgset "$CLONE_SKB"
pgset "$PKT_SIZE"
pgset "$DELAY"

pgset "dst_min 192.168.6.1"
pgset "dst_max 192.168.63.255"

pgset "flows 100"
pgset "flowlen 1"

PGDEV=/proc/net/pktgen/pgctrl

echo "Running... ctrl^C to stop"
pgset "start"
echo "Done"
#pgset "stop"
```

Comment: If your host has two interfaces named `eth1` and `eth2`, why do you think you could find any information on `eth0`? Also, are you saying that you are trying to send from `eth1`, through the switch, and back to `eth2`? You are going to have problems with that.

Comment: I am sorry .. thats a typo. It should be `eth1`. I am sending from eth1 and then through switch and back to eth2.

Comment: That is actually going to shortcut through your own host.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. But that doesn't happen here since the destination IPs are quite random and doesn't match `eth2` IP address.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense since `eth2` will drop traffic not destined to its MAC address, which will not be resolved by IP addresses not it own, and if you are sending traffic to it, then it will shortcut. You really need two hosts to run this type of test. By the way, almost all modern switches perform switching in hardware, and they give you wire-speed switching. Even cheap switches do this because switching hardware has become a commodity.

Comment: Another problem you may have is that your traffic generation tool may be inserting itself at a layer in the network stack that is lower than your capture tool. That would bypass outgoing capture. Your generated traffic may also be exiting `eth2`. If both interfaces are on the same network, it is difficult to determine the exit interface. You may need to manipulate the routing table of your host.

Comment: @RonMaupin I think I missed out saying that this is an openflow switch that I am testing, not a regular commodity switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://www.mail-archive.com/netdev@vger.kernel.org/msg22176.html) it seems that pktgen sends packets below the packet capture hooks and it is not possible to see outgoing packets, untill and unless we modify the working of pktgen code.

If anyone has a different suggestion please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: Tried accepting it, but it doesn't allow me to accept untill 2 days.